# Explanation of proof that intervals are connected subspaces of $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

Maybe it's the late hours, but I've hit a brick wall trying to parse this seemingly innocuous proof that intervals are connected and would really appreciate some help. The proof goes as follows:

> Let $I$ be an interval (a set that satisfies the property $x,y\in I\implies[x,y]\subset I$) and assume it is not connected. Then there exist $O_1,O_2\subset I$ disjoint, non-empty and open in $I$, such that $I=O_1\cup O_2$. Let $x_i\in O_i$ and w.l.o.g. assume $x_1<x_2$. Let $s=\sup\{y\in O_1:y\leq x_2\}$ (the supremum exists because the set is non-empty and bounded from above). Since the $O_i$ are open in $I$, there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x_i-\varepsilon,x_i+\varepsilon)\cap I\subset O_i$ (follows from the definition of the subspace topology).

Past this point I have trouble following:

> From this it follows that $x_1+\varepsilon\leq s\leq x_2-\varepsilon$ (why?) and that $s\in(x_1,x_2)$ and therefore $s\in I$. It follows that $s$ belongs to either $O_1$ or $O_2$ and because of the fact that they're open (shouldn't it be "open in $I$"?) there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $(s-\delta,s+\delta)\subset O_i$ (why? we just know that $O_i$ is open in $I$, all we can conclude by the definition of the subspace topology is that there exists a $\delta$ such that $(s-\delta,s+\delta)\cap I\subset O_i$). Either case contradicts the definition of $s$, since if $(s-\delta,s+\delta)\subset O_1$ then $s<s+\delta\leq\sup\{y\in O_1:y\leq x_2\}$ and if $(s-\delta,s+\delta)\subset O_2$ then $\sup\{y\in O_1:y\leq x_2\}\leq s-\delta<s$ (why? I can see why the first inequality follows, but not why the second and again, I don't understand why an entire ball around $s$ has to be included along with it).

Comment: If $s<x_1+\varepsilon$, then there exists $z\in (x_1,x_1+\varepsilon)\subset O_1$ such that $s<z$, which contradicts that $s$ is the supremum.

Comment: For your next question, I agree. I think the author should have written that $O_i = I \cap U_i$ for some $U_i$ open in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $(s-\delta,s+\delta)\subset U_i$ leads to the contradiction, because either $s\in O_1$ and $(s,s+\delta)\subset I$ since all values in that interval are between $x_1$ and $x_2$, or $s\in O_2$ and $(s-\delta,s)\subset I$ since all values in that interval are between $x_1$ and $x_2$

Comment: Why should such a $z$ exist? We know that $x_1\in I$, but not whether other points of $(x_1-\varepsilon,x_1+\varepsilon)$ are too (so we can't automatically conclude everything between $x_1$ and $x_1+\varepsilon$ is in $O_1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me fill in some of what the author did not state explicitly.

Let $O_i = I \cap U_i$ for $U_i$ open in $\mathbb{R}$

We know that there exists $\varepsilon_i>0$ such that $(x_i - \varepsilon_i, x_i + \varepsilon_i) \subset U_i$, since $U_i$ is open.

Since we can find these two $\varepsilon_i$, there also exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x_i - \varepsilon, x_i + \varepsilon) \subset U_i$. (i.e. one constant for both sets)

We are given that $x_1<x_2$.

If $x_2 < x_1 + \varepsilon$, then $x_2 \in (x_1 - \varepsilon, x_1 + \varepsilon) \subset U_1$.

We know that $x_2 \in O_2 \subset I$.

Combining these gives that $x_2 \in O_1$, which contradicts that $O_1 \cap O_2 = \emptyset$.

Thus, we have that $x_2 \ge x_1 + \varepsilon$.

Since $I$ is an interval, we know that $[x_1,x_2] \subset I$, so that $(x_1, x_1 + \varepsilon) \subset I$.

Hence $(x_1, x_1 + \varepsilon) \subset U_1$ and $(x_1, x_1 + \varepsilon) \subset I$, so $(x_1, x_1 + \varepsilon) \subset O_1$.

The symmetric argument would show that $(x_2 - \varepsilon, x_2) \subset O_2$

Combining those both gives that $x_1 + \varepsilon \le s \le x_2 - \varepsilon$

Now, $s \in [x_1, x_2] \subset I$ means that either $s\in O_1 \subset U_1$ or $s\in O_2 \subset U_2$.

Either way, there exists $\delta > 0$ so that either $(s - \delta, s + \delta) \subset U_1$ or $(s - \delta, s + \delta) \subset U_2$

Let's first consider $(s - \delta, s + \delta) \subset U_1$

Using the same argument as before, we can see that if $x_2 < s + \delta$, then $x_2 \in (U_1 \cap I)$, which contradicts $O_1 \cap O_2 = \emptyset$, so $x_2 \ge s + \delta$, and hence $(s, s + \delta) \subset [s, x_2] \subset I$, so that $(s, s + \delta) \subset O_1$.

Now we have our contradiction, because $s + \delta/2 \in O_1$ and $s + \delta/2 \le x_2$, but $s + \delta/2 > s$, which contradicts the definition of $s$ in that $s$ is not an upper bound.

For the case $(s - \delta, s + \delta) \subset U_2$, by a symmetric argument we get that $(s - \delta, s) \subset O_2$, and that $s - \delta/2$ is an upper bound of $\{y \in O_1: y\le x_2\}$, which contradicts that $s$ is the least upper bound.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer finally cleared it up for me.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy I could help.